# Advice on image storing

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am currently developing an app that will browse(and more things, but this is not relevant) youtube lists. Now whenever I get a video, I display it's corresponding image and show it in a listview (or gridview, again not relevant). Now here is the dilemma: is it better to store the images locally after they are downloaded, or do we download them every time we want them showed, i.e:
 `this._image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://domain.com/content/someImage.jpg"));`

Comment: What is the reason of keeping the image? Could you not just save the path and render the image from that path?

Comment: The reason is after relaunching the app the images will be downloaded again and a list might have 100-200 videos, and you can have many lists. Downloading all these images everytime is bandwidth heavy.

Comment: Ops, I apparently wasn't in the "asp.net-mvc" tag filter :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to see what YouTube has to say on the matter; I'm sure it's got something regarding this in its developer API documentation to note their preferred approach to it.

That said, take this as general advice; when you're constantly querying another system, you generally want to limit how annoying you are. Now, YouTube's not going to notice the load of one app, of course, but it's still a good habit to keep. Generally speaking, I'd prefer to split the difference: cache the image based on video ID and hold it for X hours, so if the user pulls up the same video in a search 20 times you didn't request a thumbnail 20 times as well.

That way you keep the result relevant by updating the image every day or two (assuming they searched for the video again).

Edit: Right, app. Mobile. Bandwidth. Godawful data caps. My advice is more important then and you *probably* want to make it cache for a couple of days to be safe, but have a hard cap of how many video thumbnails you keep at a time so you're not the app taking up 100MB of space on some guy's 8GB phone.

If you want to be super user friendly, throw something in the settings somewhere to let people change the approach to query every time, or cache for a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your usage model. The correct term would be 'cache' image locally 'or' fetch from servers each time you want to show image. If user experience is of higher priority than showing the latest image snapshot of youtube videos (which very likely isn't going to change for same video) - then **cache the images locally, with an expiry time**. This would be helpful in having a faster user experience and also save some network bandwidth. Caching with expiry would ensure you are not filling up memory on device with too many unnecessary images and also as images get old, they will be less relevant and removed and you can fetch new ones.

Caching policy (the way you determine when an image is not of high importance and how long it should remain) will be an interesting problem and can have significant impact on the user experience